# Reserved words when performing a join

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-joins

This is my first assignment for a GIS class, so bear with me. I have voting data for the state of California, and one thing I need to do is join a precinct voting data layer with a counties layer. When I click Validate Join, I get the following error message:

"Field names that match reserved words should not be used in database schema and can cause the join to fail. The following fields match reserved words;
- [TYPE] from < PrecinctVotingData >"

I know it's a simple fix but I'm stuck at this point. What should I do?

Comment: In catalog you can rename TYPE to another field name. Right-click layer, Properties, Fields, enter a new name for Field Name.

Comment: I think the keyword here is 'can',  proceed with the join and have a look at the output to see what it does with the TYPE field, it might rename it TYPE_1. What database is your join *to* data in? A reserved word should have caused problems long before this.